# Error running playbook that only affects one of the hosts

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-awx

I've recently started using more and more Ansible, and especially AWX, for simple repetitive tasks. Below is a playbook for downloading, installing and configuring logging via a Bash script. The script is for two hosts: Ubuntu 20.04 and CentOS 7.6, and for the latter, making some changes to SELinux is required.

The question is, why am I getting an error for the Ubuntu only and not the CentOS also?

Here is the playbook:

```
# Download an run Nagios Log Server configuration script
---
- name: nagios-log configure
  hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  
  - name: Distribution
    debug: msg="{{ ansible_distribution }}"

  - name: Download setup-linux.sh
    get_url: 
      url: http://10.10.10.10/nagioslogserver/scripts/setup-linux.sh
      validate_certs: no
      dest: /tmp/setup-linux.sh
      
  - name: Change script permission
    file: dest=/tmp/setup-linux.sh mode=a+x
      
  - name: Run setup-linux.sh
    shell: /tmp/setup-linux.sh -s 10.10.10.10 -p 5544
    register: ps
    failed_when: "ps.rc not in [ 0, 1 ]"
    
  - name: Install policycoreutils if needed
    yum: 
      name: 
        - policycoreutils
        - policycoreutils-python
      state: latest
    when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'
        
  - name: Check if policy file exists
    stat:
      path: /etc/selinux/targeted/active/ports.local
    register: result
    when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'

  - name: Check whether line exists
    find:
      paths: /etc/selinux/targeted/active/ports.local 
      contains: '5544'
    register: found
    when: result.stat.exists == True
    
  - name: Add SELinux policy exception if missing
    command: semanage port -a -t syslogd_port_t -p udp 5544
    when: found.matched > 0
    
  - name: Restart rsyslog
    systemd:
      name: rsyslog
      state: restarted
      enabled: yes
```

And here is the error output when running the playbook on AWX:

```
TASK [Check whether line exists] ***********************************************
fatal: [Ubuntu.domain.corp]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'result.stat.exists == True' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (result.stat.exists == True): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stat'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/tmp/awx_154_1811rny6/project/nagios-log.yml': line 39, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Check whether line exists\n    ^ here\n"}
ok: [Centos.domain.corp]
```

For reasons I can't comprehend, the CentOS server is fine, but the Ubuntu is getting a strange error that I don't understand. I've tried other methods to achieve the same logic as the `when` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error, because you register the variable `result` in

```yaml
  - name: Check if policy file exists
    stat:
      path: /etc/selinux/targeted/active/ports.local
    register: result
    when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'
```

But because of `when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'` this does not run on Ubuntu and therefor the variable `result` does not exist when running the playbook on Ubuntu.

To fix this (and run the task using `result` on CentOS only as well) you can change it to this:

```yaml
  - name: Check whether line exists
    find:
      paths: /etc/selinux/targeted/active/ports.local 
      contains: '5544'
    register: found
    when:
    - ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'
    - result.stat.exists == True

  - name: Add SELinux policy exception if missing
    command: semanage port -a -t syslogd_port_t -p udp 5544
    when:
    - ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'
    - found.matched > 0
```

Or you can put all CentOS specific tasks in a [block](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html) like this:

```yaml
  - name: CentOS specific tasks
    block:
    - name: Install policycoreutils if needed
      yum: 
        name: 
          - policycoreutils
          - policycoreutils-python
        state: latest
    - name: Check if policy file exists
      stat:
        path: /etc/selinux/targeted/active/ports.local
      register: result
    - name: Check whether line exists
      find:
        paths: /etc/selinux/targeted/active/ports.local 
        contains: '5544'
      register: found
      when: result.stat.exists == True      
    - name: Add SELinux policy exception if missing
      command: semanage port -a -t syslogd_port_t -p udp 5544
      when: found.matched > 0
    when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'
```

Or you can put them in their own file and [include that file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html). There are actually a lot of ways to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand what the problem was, and I used the first method to solve the problem! Also, wow I didn't you know you can put all of those things into a big block - I'll be sure to use that in the future.